# Postgres: Convert text[] column to character varying

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using `REGXP_MATCHES` for pattern matching to retrieve the string I want

For example:
`SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('abc xyz|def|ghi', '[A-Za-z ]*')` should give me `abc xyz`.

However, in the output column, it gives me `{"abc xyz"}`.

The datatype for `REGEXP_MATCHES` is `text[]`.

Is there a way I can convert it to `character varying` datatype?

I have tried casting it using `SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('abc xyz|def|ghi', '[A-Za-z ]*')::character varying`, but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereference the first element:

```
SELECT (REGEXP_MATCH('abc xyz|def|ghi', '[A-Za-z ]*'))[1];

 regexp_match 
--------------
 abc xyz
(1 row)
```